# Nth Child Selector for rows of 2 and 3

Tags: css

I'm displaying rows of data in 2s and 3s. I want to make sure that the 2nd, 5th, 7th, 10th, 12th item (and so on...) don't have a margin but I'm not sure how to target these using `nth-child`

At the moment I'm just using `2n` and `5n` but this doesn't work as of course `2n` targets 6th, 8th etc

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use selectors `5n` and `5n+2`:

```css
div:nth-child(5n), div:nth-child(5n+2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>14</div>
<div>15</div>
<div>16</div>
<div>17</div>
<div>18</div>
<div>19</div>
<div>20</div>
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks for this.